# SpreadsheetML retrieve all used Stylesheets

Tags: excel, openxml-sdk

i want to get all used Stylesheets from my Excel xslx file.
Have i iterate through all cells or can i get on another way all used Stylesheets?

Best regards
Brian Dahl

Answer (score 0):

Save and close the file. Rename it to from .xlsx to .zip. Then enter the zip file and look for a folder called "xl". In there is a file called "styles.xml".

Comment: yes that i have done but there i see all Stylesheet not their only used....